# Using shift+F2 opens a dialog with two options

Tags: vb.net

VB.NET 2022

When pressing Shift+F2 over a line of code that reference to a form(dialog), its open another dialog with two options:

1-anyname.designer 2-anyname.vb

Before the same command opens the form(dialog) directly on the 2nd option anyname.vb without extra steps.

Is there a way to make it work as before.

Aimcorp

Comment: Everything that can be changed about VS is in the Options dialogue. All new users should have a thorough look through it see what can be changed and what they think needs to be changed.

Comment: I am not a new user.  I know about the option dialogue.  But I don't see a way to get that as before.  Been a programmer for 40 years.  Been with VS from the very beginning.  Thanks